# не могу разобраться с оператором 'or' в Python

Tags: python

Только начал с нуля изучать, заранее прошу прощения если вопрос тупой или неправильно написан. Не могу разобраться. Пытаюсь написать, чтобы строка  спрашивала что ввести, когда человек вводит что-то,  х принимает тип написанного(строка это или число). Но также хочу в elif перечислить типы, которые не подходят. Чтобы в итоге человек ввел только положительное число. Для этого еще нужен цикл, но и он не получается тоже. Долго уже пробую, так как знаний нет совсем, не получается и вопрос корректно в гугле задать не могу. Ответьте развернуто пожалуйста
while True:
x = input("Введите цифру")

```
if x.isdigit:
    print(int(x) / 100)
elif type(x) == float or (x < 0) or (x == 0):
    print('Введите положительное число')
else:
     print('Введите именно цифру')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Кирилл/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/test.py", line5,  in <module>             
         print(int(x) / 100)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ui'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала продумайте алгоритм.

1. Вам нужно создать цикл, который будет выполняться раз за разом до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет цифру. Легче всего этого добиться через бесконечный цикл `while`, который при удовлетворяющем нас вводе мы просто прервем через `break`
2. Нужно каждый раз проверять, что введенное пользователем - цифра. лучше это делать через встроенный строковый метод `isdigit`.
3. Если ввод нас устраивает, выполняем задуманное действие (делим на 100, например, предварительно переведя ввод пользователя в тип integer (потому что любой ввод - это строка) и прекращаем цикл через `break`.
4. Если ввод не устраивает - выводим предупреждение и продолжаем цикл дальше.

```
while True:                    # создаём бесконечный цикл
    x = input("Введите цифру") # получаем ввод пользователя
    if x.isdigit():            # проверяем, является ли ввод цифрой
        print(int(x)/100)      # выводим на печать, выполнив деление
        break                  # прерываем бесконечный цикл
    else:                      # если ввод - не цифра, то выводим
        print("Нужно ввести цифру!")  # ругательство
```

**UPDATE**

Пример использования `or`. Здесь проверка ввода производится наоборот - если ввод пользователя не является цифрой (**not** isdigit), или (or) эта цифра равна 0, то ругаемся и повторяем цикл. В противном случае, делим полученную цифру на 100:

```
while True:
    x = input("Введите цифру")
    if not x.isdigit() or int(x)==0:
        print("Нужно ввести цифру!")
    else:
        print(int(x)/100)
        break
```

Comment: А в каком случае будет уместно воспользоваться 'or'? Я просто тогда не совсем могу понять, где его применять. Если в рамках данного кода, можно как-то использовать 'or'. Ну например, если человек вводит 0 ИЛИ отрицательное число, то ему сообщение - "Введите положительное число". Или автоматическая замена 0 на 1 (if x ==0 то х += 1). Подскажите как правильно мои мысли будут отображаться в коде

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: У меня не исполняется код, даже ваш. Подскажите в чем проблема. По вашему, немного исправил и попробовал что-то добавить. Цикл не исполняется, он только выполняет до 'if', даже если оно 0 или вообще буквы. И если буквы - выдает ошибку, а если 0 - делит на 0, а elif и else как будто не видит. Вставил ваш код, - тоже самое

Comment: Я обновил код и указал ошибку

Comment: UPD: Разобрался, ошибка исчезает если как во тором варианте все подогнать под IF. А если я хочу использовать и ELIF? Или он тут не уместен?